# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in PyGtk

Tags: python, linux, kubernetes, pygtk

Hi I am tring to install PYGTK package, and ended up with the following error, can anyone please help.

```
root@cs-6000-devshell-vm-fccb9b9d-7bf3-4500-b14c-82320cb414d7:/usr/local/bin# pip install PyGtk
Collecting PyGtk
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pybnrq/PyGtk/
```

Answer (score 0):

> - Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows.
> - To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.

PyGTK often dislikes being installed using pip or setup.py so instead read the INSTALL file within the PyGTK download. This should tell you how to install it properly.

If in doubt Google the issue as lots of forums provide a step by step to install
PyGTK.

Comment: Hi Ollu_, I have tried using INSTALL file, but i found that error is because of permissions to the file, so i have tried with admin user as well, still facing same issue.